# Atmel Atmega32u4 is not working, short-cirquit...?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, atmega, atmel, microprocessors

I have a problem with Atmega32u4(QFN44 package).
This is my first custom board, I've been using arduinos.

Problem:

- VCC -> GND +-430ohm
- When connected to 5V heating up(short-cirquit)

There isn't any direct short circuit.

Schematic:
[Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZNkO.png)

Board:
[Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09wEx.png)

Comment: May be this fits better to https://electronics.stackexchange.com
430Ohm is not normal. If you have made the layout yourself, double check the pinout of the QFN. It is also possible the QFN is not soldered correctly (short cirtcuit) or component has been exchanged (bad R value or R instead of C) if you use small SMD components.
If it's realy only the MCU that is heating up, maybe it's just out of order. Try replacing it and if the next on breaks too, check what's wrong on the board. It will be difficult to help more without more information

Comment: Thanks for comment and reference to the electronics forum.
I made some upgrade and made the board again, so maybe It will work now.